# Can Java HTTP Client choak CPU if network is slow

Tags: java, performance, apache, networking, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a thread, which runs a loop and in this loop it uses `apache common http client` to create connection to a remote server and GET some data from it and then sleeps for some time. My question is if the network is slow, can the  CPU start `choaking` as the **GET** method will take longer time to fetch the data and thus return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this will cause a high CPU load, but your thread may block for a long time during the GET, which may cause your program to appear slow. The GET should be waiting for IO if the network is slow, which doesn't normally take a lot of CPU.

Comment: so when the thread is blocked, this means that thread is still using CPU and waiting for the execute call to return. Is this is synchronous call????

Comment: The thread will be using very little CPU whilst it is waiting. The call is synchronous.

Comment: so if the call is syncronous, is it not equivalent to calling a function which takes a lot of time to execute. And thus the thread will be in running state as far as CPU is concerned. So if we have many such threads doing this kind of operation CPU will start to choak

Comment: The thread is not consuming CPU whilst waiting on IO. Lots of theads could be in this 'wait' state without running high CPU on your system.

Comment: but, where did we made the thread to wait. We just called execute method. As you said execute is a synchronous call. So thread should be in running state only. Right??

Comment: The thread is in the runnng state, but it is waiting for data to come back from the GET operation. The waiting takes very little CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Network is an I/O operation, it is executed by peripheral devices usually, so CPU just waits for the operations complete. Operation system blocks the thread execution until I/O operation is completed. See [the lifecycle of threads](http://www.roseindia.net/java/thread/life-cycle-of-threads.shtml), it has a special state "blocked for I/O".

Comment: So the thread which called the execute method, will still be running and waiting for execute to return??/

Comment: @abhinav "running" and "waiting" are two different states. What do you mean?

Comment: so my question is that if network is slow, then the execute method will take more time to run and return. So the thread will be in running state for longer time. And now if I have many such threads which are in running state as execute method has not returned then wont my CPU show high usage

Comment: @abhinav Thread doesn't execute methods, it executes instructions. If an istruction is to wait, it waits for something, e.g. for a network card signal (interrupt) in your situation. Looks like you need to learn some low level stuff - how OS works, processes, threads, IO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

no, it wont stuck the CPU, but the application only will stuck (even this will not happen if you have separate networking thread)

and as network operations are I/O operation, so it doesn't use the CPU. so in that blocked-duration of your thread, CPU time will not be allotted to that blocked thread.

Comment: so when the thread is blocked, this means that thread is still using CPU and waiting for the execute call to return. Is this is synchronous call????

Comment: answer edited. and yes, it is a synchronous call. (but to I/O device only)